# Script to run a Matlab Script on the event of crash

Tags: parallel-processing, matlab

I run a matlab script (call it INIT.m) that takes care of parallel toolbox initialization and running original script. Now, sometimes, because of some unpredictable problem of data, parallel toolbox stops due to error in matlabpool job (possibly).

I would like to re-run INIT.m on the event of this kind of crash.

It can be another matlab script or may be a shell script/java code.

Any sort of help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Update (Error statements and Environment)

It gives following error message and stops (But do not exit)

`MATLAB is exiting because of fatal error
  ??? Error using ==> parallel_function at 598
  The session that parfor is using has shut down`

It also says that

`??? The client lost connection to lab 117.
This  might be due to network problems, or the interactive matlabpool job might have errored`

Environment : Linux

Comment: have you looked into `try` and `catch`?

Comment: try catch won't work, because it's a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're running some kind of UNIX. I'm also assuming with "crash" you mean that MATLAB itself dies. Before you run MATLAB you can install a hook to react on signals (using `trap`):

http://www.linuxcommand.org/wss0160.php

A list of signals:
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Bourne_Shell_Scripting/Debugging_and_signal_handling#System_signals

Obviously you'll have to figure out what signal is killing your program.

Comment: That's a nice suggestion and I also thought of it. But I am not sure about the interfacing. I'm using Ubuntu. By crash, I meant the process shuts down (I updated the question with error statements). So, actually matlab does not exit. It's connected to N number of labs and one of them is causing the error (Seg Fault). As a result, all the labs are shutting down.